# How to hide another class ui using Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qwidget

I've been trying to hide another class ui, but I can't figure it out.

As an example I have the MainWindow class and other two classes. This is a scheme of the MainWindow ui:

[---------------][---------------]

[    Class A ui    ][    Class B ui  ]

[---------------][---------------]

The top & bottom lines are just to outline the window. You can imagine it as a rectangle containing two rectangles with the classes ui inside.

When I click on a `QPushButton` in class A I want to hide class B ui.

This is a code snippet:

##### ClassA.h

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class ClassA;
}

class ClassA : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ClassA(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ClassA();
    
public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    
private:
    Ui::ClassA *ui;
};

#endif // CLASSA_H
```

###### ClassA.cpp

```
#include "classa.h"
#include "ui_classa.h"

ClassA::ClassA(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ClassA)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ClassA::~ClassA()
{
    delete ui;
}

void classA::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // code to hide ClassB ui
}
```

ClassB & MainWindow are brand new (standard). ClassB ui contains some labels, pushButtons, ... . MainWindow ui contains two QWidgets that are promoted to ClassA ui & ClassB ui.

What code should I write in the `on_pushButton_clicked()` slot? I've made some tries but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: ```show()``` and ```hide()``` or ```setVisible(False)``` should work. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#visible-prop

Comment: If I'm making UI where I need to swap between views I usually create a QStackedWidget and add the different widgets as pages inside the stacked widget. Switching view is then done by changing the index of the stacked widget.

Comment: Thank you @Homer512 for your comment! In my case I don't have an object to apply the hide method to. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Huh, your ClassA is a QWidget! You didn't show your main windows. It seems like you want to have one window with all of ClassA's content on the left and all of ClassB's content on the right. The normal approach is to make both QWidgets (which you did), then put one instance of ClassA and one of ClassB into the MainWindow. At this point, you call ```ClassA.hide()``` and it will disappear from the MainWindow's layout.

Comment: Thank you @Homer512 again!! Your comment was very helpful! I've created an instance of ClassA & ClassB into the MainWindow: I included both classes.h and I wrote `ClassA a;` and the same for ClassB... Is it correct? When I try to call the `hide()` method I get this error: "Call to non-static member function without an object argument"... What am I doing wrong? I'm sorry for these silly questions but I'm a newbie.

Comment: When your ClassA object is called ```a```, then it would be ```a.hide()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way is to add a signal in ClassA and emit it when clicking on the considered push button:

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class ClassA;
}

class ClassA : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ClassA(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ClassA();
    
public signals:
    void notifyButtonClicked();

public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    
private:
    Ui::ClassA *ui;
};

#endif // CLASSA_H
```

and in classA.cpp we have:

```
void classA::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    emit notifyButtonClicked();
}
```

now you can write this code in mainwindow constructor (assume _A is an object of ClassA):

```
connect(_A, &ClassA::notifyButtonClicked, this, [] {
     // some code for hiding ClassB
});
```

I haven't tested this, because I dont have Qt on this machine, but that should work, with possible minor modifications. If any errors appear, let me know and I will help. Also, read the signals and slots documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mohammad , your answer is very helpful. In my case I haven't any object in ClassA... do I need to have an object or can I make it work also without it? This may be a very silly question, I'm sorry, I'm just starting out both with C++ and Qt and I'm quite confused ;) .